# Can Angular be used in/with WordPress?

Tags: framework

Are there any ways to incorporate Angular (Google's Angular, not AngularJS) into Wordpress? Either in the theme or in pages/posts? I may be working on a customer-facing website for a product, and the admin site for the product will be built in Angular. There are versions of some of what will be in the admin section that will also be visible to customers. If we could re-use the Angular code in the WordPress site, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, I think this can be done. There should be a way to integrate Angular along with Wordpress for your SPA. You would have to use the wordpress REST API to connect them both though. Also, you would need to enqueue the scripts in functions.php for the same. Although I am not sure about running angular code in wordpress. You will need some sort of plugin to help wordpress understand the angular code.